# Showing an output without square brackets

Tags: output-formatting

Suppose that an output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which could be obtained from, for example,

```
D[f[x, y, z], x] / D[h[x, y, z], x]
```

I'm looking for a way to show it without the square brackets.

Currently I do that by copying the output to a text editor and removing, in this case, `[x, y, z]` with the Replace command, then copying the expression back to Mathematica. How to do this in Mathematica itself automatically?

Comment: Please post your code in a readable form (e.g. InputForm).

Comment: A more readable form added.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cell containing your output, then choose TraditionaForm from the Convert To submenu of the Cell menu. The cell will then show

[image: formula]

#### Update

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
(f^(1,0,0))[x, y, z]/(h^(1,0,0))[x, y, z] /. h_[x, y, z] -> h
```

[image: head-only]

Comment: Thank you. I have a very large expression and adding `/. h_[...] -> h` really helps. Now I feel stupid for asking the question in the first place. :-D

Answer (score 3):

A look at the `FullForm` motivates e.g. this:

```
der = Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]/Derivative[1, 0, 0][h][x, y, z];

der /. Derivative[a___][b___][c___] :> Derivative[a][b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is quite elegant, but it does change the meaning of the actual expression and not just its appearance.  For instance, `Derivative[1][Sin][x]` yields `Cos[x]`, whereas `Derivative[1][Sin]` yields `Cos[#1] &`.  Whether this matters depends on the use that the author of the question intends.

Comment: @bbgodfrey agreed on the non-equivalence of the expressions and the not-yet clear intention of the OP.

Comment: What's not clear about my intention?

Comment: @Taiki I was not sure if you just wanted the typeset expression or something related to the original expression, but the formulation of your goal is clear :D